# Is it safe to use *virtual* multiple inheritance if QObject is being derived from DIRECTLY?

Tags: c++, qt, multiple-inheritance

I understand that in general, multiple inheritance from `QObject`-derived classes (even *virtual* multiple inheritance) is not supported in Qt.

I understand the reason to be (I think) that even in the virtual inheritance case, the Qt classes do not *themselves* virtually inherit from `QObject`.  For example, if you attempt to derive a class virtually from both `QWidget` and `QThread`, this is placing the virtual inheritance in an irrelevant place in the inheritance chain and you still wind up with two `QObject` instances.

I therefore think it is safe, and supported in Qt, to use virtual inheritance where the ONLY Qt class being derived from is `QObject` itself.

I have:

```
class Top : public QObject {};

class Left : public virtual Top {};

class Right : public virtual Top {};

class Bottom : public Left, public Right {}; // Is this safe, and supported by Qt?
```

Note that instances of `Bottom` truly have only one instance of `Top` (and hence only one instance of `QObject`), so it seems that the rationale for avoiding multiple inheritance in Qt (even *virtual* multiple inheritance) does not apply here.

The above construct nonetheless results in the Qt compiler warning `Class Bottom inherits from two QObject subclasses Left and Right. This is not supported!`.

Am I correct?  Is it safe to ignore the Qt compiler warning in this specific scenario?  Is the above construct, involving virtual multiple inheritance **directly** from QObject, safe and supported in Qt?

Comment: How does Qt actually use this class? If you're just passing in a pointer or reference to `QObject`, then it's fine. If it somewhere attempts to get a member offset, instead of using pointer-to-member, it may not be.

Comment: @Useless I hope to be able to tie in Qt signals and slots for `Top`, `Left`, `Right`, and/or `Bottom`.

Comment: OK, so whether it works or not depends on the details of how those are implemented. I have no idea what the answer is in that case, but at least it's clear for the next passing Qt expert ...

Comment: @Dan: You'll be able to tie in signals and slots for `Top` only.  And `Top` can use virtual functions to delegate implementation to its subclasses, but Qt won't know how to deal with them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, multiple inheritance from `QObject` is not supported by Qt in any way.

The problem is not with virtual inheritance, it's Qt's meta-object system.  Each `QObject` base class has an associated `QMetaObject` which manages signals, slots, properties, etc, and each meta-object knows its parent `QObject` so e.g. signals which exist in parent classes can be handled.  The Qt moc is not able to deal with multiple inheritance from `QObject` or any of its sub-classes.

Comment: Indeed - even defining a `signal` for the `Right` class (and presumably `Left` is the same, as well), results in a *compiler* error on the following `moc`-produced line: `Right *_t = static_cast<Right *>(_o);` with `_o` a `QObject`.  So not only is the construct not supported by Qt - it won't even compile.

Comment: I wonder whether it's on the list for Qt to someday support multiple inheritance of `QObject`-derived classes.