# Can one hide parts of the inheritance hierarchy in C++?

Tags: c++, qt, oop, inheritance

Consider the following:

Class `B` inherits publicly from class `A`. Both are provided in a library and I cannot modify them.

I want to implement a class `Foo` that derives from `B`, but I want to allow users of `Foo` to use only public functions of `A` and `Foo` (not from `B`). For them, it is not relevant that `Foo` inherits from `B`, this is in principle an implementation detail that I cannot avoid.

So, in principle I want `Foo` to inherit publicly from `A`, but privately from `B`.

Is there some construct in C++ that would allow me to do this?

I must add that virtual inheritance is not an option since `A`, in my case, derives from `QObject` (see [Is it safe to use *virtual* multiple inheritance if QObject is being derived from DIRECTLY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445863/is-it-safe-to-use-virtual-multiple-inheritance-if-qobject-is-being-derived-fro)).

(NB: For interested people: in my case, `A` is `QWindow` and `B` is `Qt3DExtras::Qt3DWindow`)

Comment: does `struct foo : A { B b; }` work?

Comment: Just don't document that your class derives from B. Say it derives from A. This isn't a method to stop a determined user wanting access to B, but then nothing else is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The closest you can do in c++ is this:

```
class Foo : private B {
  public:
    using A::foo; // Expose function foo in Foo's API.
    using A::bar;
    operator A&() { return *this; } // Implicit conversion to `A` when needed.
    operator A const&() const { return *this; }
};
```

Comment: `A * a = pointer_to_foo`, which is the important part of Qt, doesn't work

Comment: @Danh, another reason to prefer references. You can't add pointer coercion since they are built-in types. The OP will have to explicitly cast.

Comment: yes, I also prefer to use references, but AFAIK it's how Qt works in general

Comment: @StoryTeller Consider to provide a conversion to `const A &` as well.

Comment: @RalphTandetzky, yeah that's a good idea. My pet peeve with c++ is that there is not way to supply both in one go

Comment: Indeed, this solution does what I need. In my case, the header file becomes quite large because of the inheritance hierarchy (`QWindow` and `QObject` have many functions), and I had to make `QObject` a friend of the class to allow for signal-slot connections. Further, since I also derive from my class `Foo`, I replaced the private inheritance by a protected inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is Qt, I think this is the closest you can do:

```
struct Foo : A {
    // override all function of A, forward its to B
private:
    B b; // or pointer to B, it's depend on your design
};
```

Comment: This gives you two `A`s inside a `Foo`, the inherited one and one as part of `b`. (Specifically, there are two `QWindow`s, which sounds wrong -- this is just *one* window, isn't it?) That may not be desired. I also suppose that a `Foo` must *be*  a `B`, for example because a pointer to it is stored as a pointer to a `B`.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider OP said _For them, it is not relevant that Foo inherits from B_

Comment: Not for the *users*, but somewhere must be a requirement -- it cannot be avoided, after all.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I think OP had this in mind _ an implementation detail that I cannot avoid_ Let him clarify this requirement a bit

Comment: The ideal would be to have a normal `QWindow` that contains a widget for the 3D representation, which would correspond to this answer. However, currently in Qt3D one must create a window for it. In principle one could use `QWidget::createWindowContainer()` to embed the window, but I think that the question by itself is interesting and could come up in another context, which is why I asked it.